# Amazon Mailing issue: PHP Mail is going into spam

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have configured Amazon EC2 of PHP and mysql. Now i have pointed my domain to Amazon EC2 elastic IP. My Domain is hosted at google domain.

Problem i am facing is that, my emails from the server is going into SPAM folder. I have seen many posts related to this problem. Some is saying is to change MX records for the domain route53. But i am unable to change it because my domain is not register to AWS.

Please guide me if any one face the similar problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are running your mail server directly on your EC2 instance, you will constantly fight problems like this.

Do yourself a favor and use Amazon SES instead for your outgoing mail, (or another transaction email provider). EC2 servers often get blacklisted because of abuse by spammers, as you are seeing.

You won't have to make any DNS changes to send outgoing email via SES.

Comment: Can you guide me to configure SES. It would be helpfull for me.

Comment: Its all pretty much here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-email.html. For the simplest use cases, use their SMTP interface.